# Scheduled tasks wake up computer but not shut it down

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I set up a scheduled task waking up the computer. After the task finishes execution, the computer shuts down shortly.

Is there a way to wake it up, but NOT shut it down?

Comment: The task starts the computer up. It doesn’t shut it down. Whatever put the computer to sleep to begin with does it again. It’s hard to ask for the computer to sleep but then not sleep. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Appleoddity Are you saying it is something else instead of the finish of the schedule task that shuts down the computer?

Comment: Try to create a script to shut down computer or add shut down command line to this task if it execute a script, and cofigure it again. It will shut down after execute actions. So we need to contact script gays for details.

Comment: @Joy What I want is exactly the opposite thing. I didn't configure any shut down script, but the computer shuts down automatically. How could I remove the shut down action?